# Extract all numeric substrings which are followed by a particular character

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode, delimiter

If I have a string "123x456x78", how could I explode it to return an array containing "123" as the first element and "456" as the second element?  Basically, I want to take strings that are followed by "x" (which is why "78" should be thrown out).  I've been messing around with regular expressions, but am having trouble.

**EDIT**: if the string were "123x456x78x" I would need three elements: "123", "456", "78".  Basically, for each region following an "x", I need to record the string up until the next "x".

Comment: `$newString = explode("x","123x456x78");` this result? or something else? or do you then want to remove the last result of `78`?

Comment: Just curious....is this related to LimeSurvey?

Comment: Nope, not related to LimeSurvey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loads of different ways, but here's a **RegEx** as you were trying that:

```
$str = "123x456x78";
preg_match_all("/(\d+)x/", $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "123" [1]=> string(3) "456" }
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer since the OP edited the question and it still applies.

Comment: @Class Well, my answer does work correctly as well... It's just that the last element of the array will be an empty string, but who cares, since it'll be unset anyway?

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = explode("x", "123x456x78");
```

and then

```
unset($arr[2]);
```

if you really can't stand that poor 78.

Answer (score 1):

use explode

```
$string='123x456x78';

$res = explode('x', $string);
if(count($res) > 0) {
    echo $res[0];
    if(count($res) > 1) {
        echo $res[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = "123x456x78";
$array = explode("x", $var);
array_pop($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code to explode. It works well!

```
   <?php
    $str='123x456x78';
    $res=explode('x',$str);
    unset($res[count($res)-1]); // remove last array element
    print_r($res);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To explode AND remove the last result:

```
$string='123x456x78'; // original string

$res = explode('x', $string); // resulting array, exploded by 'x'

$c = count($res) - 1; // last key #, since array starts at 0 subtract 1

unset($res[$c]); // unset that last value, leaving you with everything else but that.
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm all for regular expressions, in this case it might be easier to just use PHP's array functions...

```
$result=array_slice(explode('x',$yourstring),0,-1);
```

This should work because only the last element returned by explode won't be followed by an 'x'. Not sure if explode will add an empty string as the last element if it ends on 'x' though, you might have to test that...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a pattern to capture the digits and match the `x`, you can simplify the output array by matching the digits and lookahead for the `x`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eNVOf))

```
$string = '123x456x78';

preg_match_all('/\d+(?=x)/', $string, $m);
var_export($m[0] ?? null);
```